# Can you determine list of labels for existing EntityRecognizer (NER)?

Tags: spacy

I know in the past you could get the list of labels for an EntityRecognizer as follows:

```
nlp.entity.cfg[u'actions']
```

(From https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/441)

But, it seems this had been disallowed. Is there any way to do this now?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In spaCy 3 do `nlp.get_pipe('ner').labels`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following :

`nlp.entity.labels`

It outputs the following tuple :

`('CARDINAL',
 'DATE',
 'EVENT',
 'FAC',
 'GPE',
 'LANGUAGE',
 'LAW',
 'LOC',
 'MONEY',
 'NORP',
 'ORDINAL',
 'ORG',
 'PERCENT',
 'PERSON',
 'PRODUCT',
 'QUANTITY',
 'TIME',
 'WORK_OF_ART')`

Comment: This does not seem to be supported in spaCy 3. `AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'entity'`

Answer (score 0):

As of spaCy version 3.7

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
print(ner.labels)
```

Outputs:

`('CARDINAL', 'DATE', 'EVENT', 'FAC', 'GPE', 'LANGUAGE', 'LAW', 'LOC', 'MONEY', 'NORP', 'ORDINAL', 'ORG', 'PERCENT', 'PERSON', 'PRODUCT', 'QUANTITY', 'TIME', 'WORK_OF_ART')`